# cakePHP 3.0 HABTM relations save data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to make this tutorial http://miftyisbored.com/complete-tutorial-habtm-relationships-cakephp/ in cakePHP 3.0

I have 3 tables: recipes, ingredients and ingredients_recipes.

When making a recipe, I want to select ingredients. Then I want to store the recipe_id and ingredient_id in the ingredients_recipes table, but fail to do so. I think there's something wrong in my RecipesController. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

**Problem:**

```
$ingredients = $this->Recipes->Ingredients->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
// => THIS GIVES ME THE MESSAGE "The recipe could not be saved. Please, try again."

$ingredients = $this->Ingredients->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
// => THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR "Call to a member function find() on boolean"
```

When I do var dump (when using this $this->Recipes->Ingredients->find) I get this:

```
array(3) { 
   ["recipe_name"]=> string(4) "Test" 
   ["recipe_description"]=> string(4) "Test" 
   ["Recipe"]=> array(1) { 
      ["Ingredient"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } 
   } 
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `recipe_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `recipe_description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`recipe_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `ingredients` (
  `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ingredient_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ingredient_description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ingredient_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `ingredients_recipes` (
  `ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ingredient_id`,`recipe_id`)
);
```

Here's my code below:

Model > Entity:

**Recipe**

```
class Recipe extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'recipe_id' => true,
        'recipe_name' => true,
        'recipe_description' => true,
    ];
}
```

**Ingredient**

```
class Ingredient extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'ingredient_id' => true,
        'ingredient_name' => true,
        'ingredient_description' => true,
    ];
}
```

**IngredientsRecipe**

```
class IngredientsRecipe extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'ingredient' => true,
        'recipe' => true,
    ];
}
```

Model > Table :

**RecipesTable**

```
class RecipesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('recipes');
        $this->displayField('recipe_name');
        $this->primaryKey('recipe_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Recipes', [
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('Ingredients', [
            'className' => 'Ingredients',
            'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id' 
        ]);
    }
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->requirePresence('recipe_name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('recipe_name')

            ->requirePresence('recipe_description', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('recipe_description')

            ->requirePresence('Ingredients', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('Ingredients');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

**IngredientsTable**

```
class IngredientsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('ingredients');
        $this->displayField('ingredient_name');
        $this->primaryKey('ingredient_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Ingredients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->belongsToMany('Recipies', [
            'className' => 'Recipies',
            'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes',
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'recipe_id' 
        ]);
    }
}
```

**IngredientsRecipesTable**

```
class IngredientsRecipesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('ingredients_recipes');

        $this->displayField('recipe_id');

        $this->primaryKey(['recipe_id', 'ingredient_id']);

        $this->belongsTo('Recipies', [
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('Ingredients', [
            'foreignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

Controller:

**RecipesController**

```
public function add()
{
    $recipe = $this->Recipes->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $recipe = $this->Recipes->patchEntity($recipe, $this->request->data);
        // var_dump($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Recipes->save($recipe)){
            $this->Flash->success('The recipe has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The recipe could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $recipes = $this->Recipes->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);

    $ingredients = $this->Recipes->Ingredients->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    // => THIS GIVES ME THE MESSAGE "The recipe could not be saved. Please, try again."
    $ingredients = $this->Ingredients->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    // => THIS GIVES ME THE ERROR "Call to a member function find() on boolean"

    $this->set(compact('recipe', 'recipes', 'ingredients'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['recipe']);
}
```

Template > Recipes

**add.ctp**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($recipe); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Recipe') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('recipe_name', array(
                'label' => 'Name'
                )
            );
            echo $this->Form->input('recipe_description', array(
                'label' => 'Description'
                )
            );

            echo $this->Form->input('Recipes.Ingredients', ['multiple'=>true]);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: One thing is noted is that the recipes table yo have 'recipe_id' and not `id`. Your `recipes` table should have columns as `id`, `name`, `description`. If they are already setup like that in DB, then you need to fix your code to reflect that. Take a look at CakePHP standards: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html#

Comment: Also I failed to notice that is a tutorial for CakePHP 2. There are a couple of tutorials in the CakePHP book that are 3.0 examples, namely a Blog and Bookmark tutorial.

Comment: Yeah I know the tutorial is for cakePHP 2.0, but I want to remake the tutorial in cakePHP 3.0

Comment: Well.. ok then. I would say, run your code on a server and come back with errors. Someone in here should be able to help you at that point. Or better yet, create your database tables correctly per CakePHP's convention (See docs), use bin/cake bake all Recipes, etc and look at your code.... then add what else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this tutorial could help: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html.

It explains exactly how to set up HABTM relations, adding tags to bookmarks, and more.

Good luck and happy coding :)